# Windows To Go - prevent internal disks from going online

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, automount, windows-to-go

I created Windows To Go from Windows 8.1 Pro according to these manual http://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/. But host PC disks are online by default. How I can keep them offline?

I disable automount with `mountvol /N`, so they seem untouched by WTG system. Still I rather to keep internal disks offline.

Thanks for suggestions and sorry for terrible English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured out how to do this. First, you log in to Windows that is on your external drive/usb drive. Then you open `Diskpart` by pressing `Windows+R`, then enter `diskpart.exe`. Then type in "`SAN POLICY=OfflineInternal`" Without the "". Then press Enter. It should say Operation Completed successfully. Just reboot and you are done. If you want to revert it, type "`SAN POLICY=OnlineALL`"
Hope this helped!